# Woocommerce product attributes not working on iOS

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce website build on **wordpress/woocommerce**. lots of products are there and each and every product has different attributes related to product.
Every thing running well till yesterday.
But yesterday I update wordpress as well as woocommerce.

My current version of both are Wordpress - **4.2.1** and Woocommerce - **2.4.7**.

My problem is after updating woocommerce, product attributes which appear as drop-down not working on iOS device(I tested on iOS **7.x.x** and **8.x.x**) except iOS devices that attributes are working on each and every devices like android, windows phone, and also different OS.

I am not changing anything in product attributes and I also update table and products after updating woocommerce version. So, why this not working?
Is this bug of woocommerce 2.4.7 ? or something missing from my side.

Anyone has same problem? If someone know solution about this please let me know.

Appreciate your answer and opinion, Thanks in advance.